# Proposing a list of writing books

Tags: discussion, list-question, writing-se-ebook

I understand that lists or specific book requests are forbidden on SE groups, though I don’t really see why, apart from the fact it would take up lots of time and generate multiple duplicates.

I also saw that on meta, there were several questions about how to deal with lists of books, but I don’t think this is a duplicate because I proposing having the list, or lists,  in a specific place and not part of the regular Q/A.

Anyways, a compromise may be to offer a recommended book list for writers. The potential writing books could be proposed in a category like plot, style, characterization, publishing, or romance genre, and then selected with a number of up votes.

I am raising this issue because while manuals are far from the only way to learn about writing, they are a great learning tool.  Some Writing.SE members that need to learn more about writing could refer to this list for reference.

**P.S.** I saw [a couple](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/612/what-questions-should-we-compile-into-a-writers-se-ebook) [of posts](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/617/what-form-should-a-writers-se-book-take) about compiling a Writing.SE ebook, what happened to that project?

Comment: I've seen other SE sites compile resource lists (books, journals, blogs, whatever makes sense in their scope) on meta.  From what I've seen this is best done with one community-wiki answer so that everybody can edit.  (Make sections within that for categories.)  If you anticipate the list being *really* long in the end, multiple answers (one per category) can also work.

Comment: As for the ebook, I don't know -- you might want to draw attention to that question (link to it here or bring it up in chat).  My guess is that nobody has been sufficiently motivated to move it from "idea" to "first stages of an actual plan".  Anybody who'd like to work on that (or any other) project should feel free to step up!

Answer (score 1):

I just found in this 4 years old Q/A almost what I was proposing

[What are good reads about writing?](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/148/what-are-good-reads-about-writing)